# Address[] can not assign to Bytes[] - Subgraph Build

Tags: typescript, graphql, ethereum, smartcontracts, subgraph

I don't know what went wrong but when i try `npm run build`  which runs `graph build` it throws error mentioned bellow

```
Compile subgraphERROR TS2322: Type '\~lib/array/Array\<\~lib/@graphprotocol/graph-ts/common/numbers/Address\>' is not assignable to type '\~lib/array/Array\<\~lib/@graphprotocol/graph-ts/common/collections/Bytes\>'.

entity.targets = event.params.targets;
\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~
in src/dcode-dao.ts(43,20)

✖ Failed to compile subgraph: Failed to compile data source mapping: 1 compile error(s)
Error: Failed to compile data source mapping: 1 compile error(s)
at Compiler.\_compileDataSourceMapping (/home/eu4/Desktop/DcodeGraph/node_modules/@graphprotocol/graph-cli/src/compiler/index.js:320:13)
at /home/eu4/Desktop/DcodeGraph/node_modules/@graphprotocol/graph-cli/src/compiler/index.js:224:20
at updateInDeepMap (/home/eu4/Desktop/DcodeGraph/node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable.js:1971:22)
at updateInDeepMap (/home/eu4/Desktop/DcodeGraph/node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable.js:1980:23)
at updateInDeepMap (/home/eu4/Desktop/DcodeGraph/node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable.js:1980:23)
at Map.updateIn (/home/eu4/Desktop/DcodeGraph/node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable.js:1278:26)
at /home/eu4/Desktop/DcodeGraph/node_modules/@graphprotocol/graph-cli/src/compiler/index.js:223:24
at /home/eu4/Desktop/DcodeGraph/node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable.js:3016:46
at List.\__iterate (/home/eu4/Desktop/DcodeGraph/node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable.js:2206:13)
at IndexedIterable.mappedSequence.\__iterateUncached (/home/eu4/Desktop/DcodeGraph/node_modules/immutable/dist/immutable.js:3015:23)
UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION: Error: The AssemblyScript compiler crashed when compiling this file: 'src/dcode-dao.ts'
Suggestion: try to comment the whole file and uncomment it little by little while re-running the graph-cli until you isolate the line where the problem happens.
Also, please contact us so we can make the CLI better by handling errors like this. You can reach out in any of these links:

- Discord channel: https://discord.gg/eM8CA6WA9r
- Github issues: https://github.com/graphprotocol/graph-cli/issues
```

I was creating a DAO contract using Openzeppelin Governor contract and this contract emits an event called

```
ProposalCreated (uint256 proposalId, address proposer, address\[\] targets, uint256\[\] values, string\[\] signatures, bytes\[\] calldatas, uint256 startBlock, uint256 endBlock, string description)
```

You can see that it emits an Address array named targets. when i run `npm run codegen` it create this parameter as an Address Array type object. and in side the build script it assigns to a Bytes Array type Object.

and it throws the error.

```
ERROR TS2322: Type '\~lib/array/Array\<\~lib/@graphprotocol/graph-ts/common/numbers/Address\>' is not assignable to type '\~lib/array/Array\<\~lib/@graphprotocol/graph-ts/common/collections/Bytes\>'.

entity.targets = event.params.targets;
\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~\~
in src/dcode-dao.ts(43,20)
```

i have mentioned whole error console on top of the issue.

inshort
Address Array can not be Assigned to the Bytes Array.

Tell me if you need any screen shot of the error.

Since the `npm run codegen` created the this Address and Bytes object automatically i can't change it.

these build was automatically generated on `graph init` so i think this should work just fine.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have done the following and it worked

```
entity.targets = changetype<Bytes[]>(event.params.targets)
```

here the `event.params.targets` is an `Address[]` and `entity.targets` is a `Bytes[]`
so I have changed its type with `changetype<Bytes[]>`.

I don't know if this is a good fix, but it worked.

Comment: changetype method doesn't exist in graph-ts

Answer (score 0):

in src/dcode-dao.ts

->> Import Bytes.

`import {Bytes} from "@graphprotocol/graph-ts";`

->> Type conversion

`entity.targets = event.params.targets.map<Bytes>((target: Bytes) => target)`;